# Security of permutation function

Tags: permutations

I have a question related to permutation. If I have a 10-bit number: {0101110010}. I want to swap even position bits to adjacent odd bits and odd positions to adjacent even bits, such that I get {1010110001}. Can I call it an alternate permutation?If I use it for a security purpose such that the any other party finds hard to get a correct sequence, so is it secure enough to be used?
Thanks

Comment: It is a simple method and you published it here, so it is not secure.

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen..Thank you for your reply. I am just curious that can it be called permutation?...its not my real design...its a part of a design..

Comment: Well, yes, by nomenclature this is a permutation of the bits.

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen..Thank you... One more thing..can you please tell me how can I write it mathematically?